# Excluding AutoConfigureTestDatabase from MybatisTest not working

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I'm trying to configure a `Spring Boot` application that uses `MyBatis` in order to run the tests for the mappers. I see there is a [`MybatisTest`](https://github.com/mybatis/spring-boot-starter/blob/master/mybatis-spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/mybatis/spring/boot/test/autoconfigure/MybatisTest.java) annotation that may be useful...but it does autoconfigure an embedded datasource

I noticed the annotation declares an `excludeAutoConfiguration` parameter. I went ahead and set it with `AutoConfigureTestDatabase`, but it doesn't do anything. Documentation states `Auto-configuration exclusions that should be applied for this test.` so it should work.

Why wouldn't `excludeAutoConfiguration` work in this case?

> I know the autoconfigured embedded datasource can be disabled using `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)`, but I'm trying to do the same while using only the `MybatisTest` annotation, e.g.: `@MybatisTest(excludeAutoConfiguration = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.class)`.